# Problema websocket python

Tags: python, variables, websocket

estoy haciendo un bot de trading y para ello estoy utilizando un websocket para
sacar información de mercado. El problema es que a la hora de formular las funciones y poner dentro la variable (ws) que es el objeto del websocketapp no me lo reconoce, es decir , que en las funciones no me aparece que exista ws.

He intentado cambiar el orden de las lineas por si acaso y seguía sin funcionar creo que es una tontería pero sigo sin encontrar el error.
Este es el código:

```
import websocket 

socket = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m"

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')
def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')
def on_message(ws,message):
    print('received connection')
    
    

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close,on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ejecute el código con Python 3.8 y me salieron mensajes `opened connection
received connection` ... estara bien, supongo.

Comment: @CandidMoe ejecutado en Python 3.7.11 me sale el error que se describe en la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias!! he probado con otra versión y me funciona será que esa en especifico tendrá algunos problemas...